# Shopify: New Github Repository Translation Issue

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am currently using Translate&Adapt as a translation application. My goal is to be able to retrieve translations associated with an existing theme, synced with Github, for a second theme that is also synced to a Github repository. In fact, when I wanted to change my published theme and change the language of my website via a language switcher, the pages were not translated at all due to "broken translations" since the "correct translations" were not synced with the new theme. I would like to know how to perform this synchronization.

I noticed that when I localized the different untranslated texts in  Translate&Adapt, there are ids associated with each translation, so I suppose that these ids are linked to the first theme and that it is necessary to either modify them or make the second theme point to these ids (I don't know if this is really possible).

- I cloned the published theme's Github repository to a second repository
- I connected the second repository to the store (it was therefore in an unpublished state)
- I made modifications to the language switcher in the unpublished theme
- I published the theme connected to the second Github repository
- I noticed that the contents of different sections were not translated.

It should be noted that this repository change is something that cannot be avoided (otherwise, we would have made the changes directly to the published theme)."

Anyway, I am open to any proposals for solutions, thank you in advance!

I also asked my question here: https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-translate-adapt/new-github-repository-translation-issue/m-p/1920126#M396